# `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs` leads to `rm: cannot remove: Device or resource busy`

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, docker, do-release-upgrade

**Problem:**

1. I have here one `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS` that I need to upgrade to `22.04 LTS`;
2. The `sudo do-release-upgrade` is being blocked by this error message:

```
Sorry, this storage driver is not supported in kernels for newer
releases

There will not be any further Ubuntu releases that provide kernel
support for the aufs storage driver.

Please ensure that none of your containers are using the aufs storage
driver, remove the directory /var/lib/docker/aufs and try again.
```

3. I already did `sudo apt remove docker*`;
4. I already did `sudo apt remove aufs*`;
5. I still cannot do `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs`, because I get `rm: cannot remove /var/lib/docker/aufs: Device or resource busy`;
6. I don't know why it is that way. I followed the instructions of the error message, but it cannot be executed.

**Question:** how can I discover what is preventing me from deleting the `/var/lib/docker/aufs` directory?

Comment: Should be dolable with `lsof /var/lib/docker/aufs`

Comment: @nobody `sudo lsof /var/lib/docker/aufs` did not solve, nor `sudo rm -rv $(lsof /var/lib/docker/aufs)` nor `sudo rm -rv lsof /var/lib/docker/aufs`. Which syntax is expected?

Comment: lsof is only showing which prozess is accessing some file or folder `lsof /home/alex/.xsession-errors
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
mate-sess  1156 alex    1w   REG   8,19    68387 50090233 /home/alex/.xsession-errors
mate-sess  1156 alex    2w   REG   8,19    68387 50090233 /home/alex/.xsession-errors
mate-sett  1294 alex    1w   REG   8,19    68387 50090233 /home/alex/.xsession-errors
mate-sett  1294 alex    2w   REG   8,19    68387 50090233 /home/alex/.xsession-errors
marco      1298 alex    1w   REG   8,19    68387`

Comment: Just reboot. The directory is likely used by `docker`, but you mention you removed `docker` whatsoever, so… I presume you didn't stop `docker` so there's still a dangling docker process. I don't know if there's just one or more though. If you don't want to spend your time on it, simply reboot.